# How to get rid of random couple pixels on bottom of text overlay

Tags: html, css, hover, overlay

I have an image with a transparent text overlay on top of it on a website I'm designing.

The transparent overlay seems to be a couple of pixels longer than the image even though I have all of the widths and heights at 100%. There are no margins or padding in play either.

I have spent the last half hour trying to figure out why its there so I can get rid of it. Any help would be appreciated.

**NOTE: I'm using a responsive CSS framework so I cannot use any absolute heights or anything**

Here is a link to the live site: http://fine-grain-2.myshopify.com/

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="six columns alpha">
    <div class="thumb"> 
       <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0209/0122/products/MG_9507_large.jpg?348" alt="" />
       <div class="overlay">
           <a href="/products/the-bowden-brown-cherry">
           <h2>THE BOWDEN</h2>
           <h3>brown + cherry</h3>
           </a>
       </div>
    </div>                  
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#home img, a, .column, .columns {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#home .six.columns {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    position: relative;
}

#home .six.columns.alpha {
    padding-right: 40px;
}

#home .six.columns .thumb {
    display: block;
    width: 100%px;
    height: 100%px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;

}

#home .six.columns .overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#home .six.columns .thumb:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}

#home .six.columns h2 {
    color: #FAFAFA;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-weight: lighter;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    margin-top: 27%;
    text-align: center;
}

#home .six.columns h3 {
    color: #FAFAFA;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: lighter;
    letter-spacing: 0.6em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Change the height to a smaller number? To be honest, I didn't notice anything wrong with your website until I looked really closely for a good 2 minutes.

Comment: I guess I am OCD haha. A quick fix though after @Miljan Puzović helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set `display: block;` to `.thumb img`.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much. I'm in a little over my head right now but learning a ton!